# Is there a way to use abbreviation in vim that ignore special characters?

Tags: vim, vi, abbreviation

I'm writing an `SQL` database script, and I use `iab` to upper case special words such as `DATABASE` or `TABLE`. I have three questions:

1. Is there a better tool to use? I prefer to avoid using a plugin as they usually come with functionality that bothers me.
2. Is there a way to make iab be case insensitive? I mean that it will correct both `set` and `Set` into `SET`?
3. Is there a way to make `iab` work when there are special or certain characters following/preceding the word? For example, I want `exec` and `exec(` to be changed into `EXEC` and `EXEC(` respectively. I can create two entries, but the question is if I can do this in a single line.

Comment: this might help: https://vi.stackexchange.com/questions/12244/case-insensitive-abbreviations

Answer (score 0):

**Better ways:** No, short of a plugin I can't see what else would be as useful as abbreviations in this context. I note that [sql_iabbr.vim](http://www.vim.org/scripts/script.php?script_id=305) is at least easy to read, and doesn't seem to contain much in the way of hidden gotchas. It's essentially a whole bunch of this:

```
inoreabbr <silent> <buffer> select <C-R>=SqlIab_ReplaceConditionally('select', 'SELECT')<CR>
```

with the following function:

```
function! SqlIab_ReplaceConditionally(original, replacement)
  " only replace outside of comments or strings (which map to constant)
  let elesyn = synIDtrans(synID(line("."), col(".") - 1, 0))
  if elesyn != hlID('Comment') && elesyn != hlID('Constant')
    let word = a:replacement
  else
    let word = a:original
  endif

  let g:UndoBuffer = a:original
  return word
endfunction
```

I think it's also worth pointing out [Abolish](https://github.com/tpope/vim-abolish) for more powerful abbreviations.

**Case insensitive:** again, I think the answer is 'No' (based on a reasonably thorough check of [the help](http://vimhelp.appspot.com/usr_24.txt.html#24.7).

**Special/certain characters:** sorry, if you need that done in one abbreviation I think you're out of luck again!

Answer (score 0):

So many questions:

> Is there a better tool to use? I prefer to avoid using a plugin as they usually come with functionality that bothers me.

Tim Pope's [Abolish.vim](https://github.com/tpope/vim-abolish) is the closest plugin which fits your needs. However with the more advanced expansions I feel like it too will fall short. I am not sure about your past plugin experiences, but Tim's plugins are usually well behaving and narrowly focused.

> Is there a way to make `iab` be case insensitive? I mean that it will correct both set and Set into SET?

No, there is no native way that I am aware of. I would recommend using Abolish if you do this regularly and have simpler expansions. Or go all the way and use a snippet plugin.

> Is there a way to make `iab` work when there are special or certain characters following/preceding the word? For example, I want exec and exec( to be changed into `EXEC` and `EXEC(` respectively. I can create two entries, but the question is if I can do this in a single line.

This can be done with a fancier expansion. It is in fact very similar to what [Rails.vim](https://github.com/tpope/vim-rails) does with it's abbreviations.

Add the following to your `~/.vim/after/ftplugin/sql.vim`:

```
function! s:selective_expand(root, good, ...)
    let [pat, extra; _] = a:0 ? a:000 : ['', '']
    let c = nr2char(getchar(0))
  if c == "" || c == "\t"
        return a:good
    elseif c =~ '\s'
        return a:good . c
    elseif pat != '' && c =~# pat
        return a:good . extra
  else
    return a:root . c
    endif
endfunction

function! s:paren_expand(root, good)
  return s:selective_expand(a:root, a:good, '[(]', "()\<left>")
endfunction

function! s:sql_expand(root, ...)
    let good = a:0 ? a:1 : toupper(a:root)
  let good = substitute(good, '[\"|]', '\\&', "g")
  let good = substitute(good, '<', '\\<lt>', "g")

    let f = 'selective_expand'
    let root = a:root
    if root =~ '($' && (!a:0 || good !~ '($')
        let root = substitute(root, '($', '', '')
        let good = substitute(good, '($', '', '')
        let f = 'paren_expand'
    endif
  let root = substitute(root, '[\"|]', '\\&', "g")
  let root = substitute(root, '<', '\\<lt>', "g")

    let roots = [root]
    if root !~# '\u' && root =~# '^\l'
        call add(roots, substitute(root, '^\l', '\u&', ''))
    endif

    for r in roots
        execute "iabbr <buffer> " . r . " <c-r>=<SID>" . f . "(\"" . r . "\", \"" . good . "\")<cr>"
    endfor

endfunction
command! -nargs=* Sqlabbrev call <SID>sql_expand(<f-args>)
```

Now you can create abbreviations in your `~/.vim/after/sql.vim` file like so:

```
Sqlabbrev select
Sqlabbrev join INNER\ JOIN
Sqlabbrev exec(
```

`Sqlabbrev` Takes 2 arguments similar to `iabbrev`. However behaves slightly differently:

- Abbreviations will always be local to the buffer
- If only 1 argument then the expansion will be the same as the first argument but made uppercase
- Using `<tab>`/`<c-]>` will make the expansion without any following spaces
- Using abbreviation followed by space will expand and add space
- If the abbreviation ends with `(` then expand with ending of `()` and place cursor inside the parens
- You must escape spaces via `\` or `<space>`. Can use keycodes
- Will create some case expansions if no uppercase letter is found in abbrevation. e.g. `Sqlabbrev select` will expand `select` and `Select`.